# Method or data not found in simple VBA program

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to get a simple task done in VBA; I am writing a GUI for an excel spreadsheet that is holding inventory. It enables users to input info into the GUI click ok and all of what they typed in is saved into the excel document.

However every time I run the below code I get a compiler error "Method or data not found".

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label4_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

'Copy input values to sheet.

Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Inventory")
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
With ws
    .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.AssetType.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.AssetNumber.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.Description.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.SerialNbr.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.CurrentUse.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.DateRec.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.FundingSource.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.Manufacturer.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.Model.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 11).Value = Me.Contract.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 12).Value = Me.Status.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 13).Value = Me.Room.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 14).Value = Me.OfficeLocation.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 19).Value = Me.Custodian.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 20).Value = Me.ExcessedDate.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 21).Value = Me.ExcessAuthorization.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 22).Value = Me.Comments.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 23).Value = Me.OutDate.Value

End With
'Clear input controls.
Me.AssetType.Value = ""
Me.AssetNumber.Value = ""
Me.Description.Value = ""
Me.SerialNbr.Value = ""
Me.CurrentUse.Value = ""
Me.DateRec.Value = ""
Me.FundingSource.Value = ""
Me.Manufacturer.Value = ""
Me.Model.Value = ""
Me.Contract.Value = ""
Me.Status.Value = ""
Me.Room.Value = ""
Me.OfficeLocation.Value ""
Me.Custodian.Value ""
Me.ExcessedDate.Value ""
Me.ExcessAuthorization.Value ""
Me.Comments.Value ""
Me.OutDate.Value ""
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
'Close UserForm.
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub Cmdbutton_add_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Model_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: What is Me.AssetType.Value  Is that the name of a text box on a form?

Comment: When you get the error, does the vba editor highlight a particular line?

Comment: IDK what the me in the name assetstype is, I saw it on a website and copied it.

Comment: As @3-14159265358979323846264 said... what line is highlighted on error?

Comment: Is AssetType the name of a control on a user form?

Comment: `Me` refers to the current class/object your code is running in. That code looks suspiciously like it's from within a form class with controls named AsssetNumber,Description, etc. If you are running it in a class that hasn't got those controls, it's no wonder you are getting that error!

Comment: Copied code without naming the form controls... That would be classic.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of a text box by the .text property of the text box.

If your text box is named AssetType it would be

```
.Cells(lRow, 1).Value = AssetType.Text
```

You may need to use the form name.

```
.Cells(lRow, 1).Value = UserForm1.AssetType.Text
```